# Server-to-API comms, can they be reliably secured using a login/cookie?

Tags: .net, api, security

A supplier I am working with as recommended connecting to their API using code similar to that below:

```
string url = "https://secure.companyapi.com"; 
string m_UserId = "user";
string m_Password = "pass";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(m_UserId, m_Password);
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Cookie sessionCookie = resp.Cookies["SMSESSION"];
```

Questions:

- Is this secure?
- What are the limitations of using this type of authentication?

(Obviously they will need to implement sticky sessions (or equivalent) on the load balancer in front of the API)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question if its secure? It is as it is using SSL "https://secure.companyapi.com", Just need to see what kind of certificate CA have issued.

This is normal type of web request we do, I don't see any pros or cons for the same.
You can use it without any issues.